# What will be the Taylor series and the radius of the convergence of $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, well it's pretty similar to the geometric series, which is $$1+x+x^2+x^3+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ So if I multiple $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$ by $x$ can I get the Taylor-series(which is in this case the Maclaurian series?

Comment: Yes you can multiply the geometric series by $x$ to get Maclaurin's series for $\dfrac{x}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint}:$ $$\frac{1+x}{1-x} = \frac{2}{1-x} - 1 \ \ \ \text{(Why?)}$$

Comment: if I multiple $(1-x)$ by $-1$ and I add $2$ it will be $x+1$

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps more appropriately, if you notice that 

$$\frac{1+x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{x}{1-x}$$

and then notice further that

$$\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1$$

you have your answer. You could also do it your way, simply by skipping the second step and leaving it as $$\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{x}{1-x}$$ since this amounts to multiplying by $x$ in the second term. Personally, though, I prefer to avoid as many $x$'s as possible as they often cause problems ;)